# model binding with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

i am using model binding in asp.net mvc 
i need  to add drop down list value to  model binding 
value of this drop down list only get by jquery or other client site programming language
with  jquery possible add to model binding?
this code not work and send  City value null to model binding

```
  var city = $("#dk_container_Cities .dk_toggle .dk_label").text();
  $("#City").val(city);
   alert(city)=="this city value correct"
  $("#frmRegisterUser").submit();
```

and

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Settings", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "result"},new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "frmRegisterUser" }))
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: What is the actual value of the `select` element when you post the form?

Comment: actual value null،and fill this value by var city = $("#dk_container_Cities .dk_toggle .dk_label").text();

Comment: `var city = ...` doesn't set a form value.  The next line looks like it tries to, but does it succeed?  What does it actually set the value of the form element with the id `City` to?  Using a browser debugging tool, monitor the actual network post to the server and see what the posted values are.

Comment: Not successful,City field in exist in usermodelview

Comment: I'm afraid you're not providing any meaningful debugging information for this issue.  You need to determine what the browser's value for that form element is when the browser posts to the server.  This is before any debugging takes place on the server.